# Nginx shows only file content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx

I have react app that was build with webpack.
Then copied to server. There are only main.js main.css package-lock.json in that folder.
But main page only shows main.js content.

This is Nginx config

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name api.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;

        server_name mydomain.com

        root /home/maksim/frontend;

        location / {
               try_files $uri /index.html /main.js;
        }
}
```

And if I use only `try_files $uri /index.html` - I will get 403 error which means index.html not found. But if `try_files $uri /index.html /main.js;` main page shows only main.js content -

```
/*
 * ATTENTION: The "eval" devtool has been used (maybe by default in mode: "development").
 * This devtool is neither made for production nor for readable output files.
 * It uses "eval()" calls to create a separate source file in the browser devtools.
 * If you are trying to read the output file, select a different devtool (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)
 * or disable the default devtool with "devtool: false".
 * If you are looking for production-ready output files, see mode: "production" (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).
 */
/******/ (function() { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "./node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js":
/*!*******************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js ***!
  \*******************************************************/
/***/ (function(__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"AbortedDeferredError\": function() { return /* binding */ AbortedDeferredError; },\n/* harmony export */   \"Action\": function() { return /* binding */ Action; },\n/* harmony export */   \"ErrorResponse\": function() { return /* binding */ ErrorResponse; },\n/* harmony export */   \"IDLE_BLOCKER\": function() { return /* binding */ IDLE_BLOCKER; },\n/* harmony export */   \"IDLE_FETCHER\": function() { return /* binding */ IDLE_FETCHER; },\n/* harmony export */   \"IDLE_NAVIGATION\": function() { return /* binding */ IDLE_NAVIGATION; },\n/* harmony export */   \"UNSAFE_DEFERRED_SYMBOL\": function() { return /* binding */ UNSAFE_DEFERRED_SYMBOL; },\n/* harmony export */   \"UNSAFE_DeferredData\": function() { return /* binding */ DeferredData; },\n/* harmony export */   \"UNSAFE_convertRoutesToDataRoutes\": function() { return /* binding */ convertRoutesToDataRoutes; },\n/* harmony export */   \"UNSAFE_getPathContributingMatches\": function() { return /* binding */ getPathContributingMatches; },\n/* harmony export */   \"UNSAFE_invariant\": function() { return /* binding */ invariant; },\n/* harmony export */   \"UNSAFE_warning\": function() { return /* binding */ warning; },\n/* harmony export */   \"createBrowserHistory\": function() { return /* binding */ createBrowserHistory; },\n/* harmony export */   \"createHashHistory\": function() { return /* binding */ createHashHistory; },\n/* harmony export */   \"createMemoryHistory\": function() { return /* binding */ createMemoryHistory; },\n/* harmony export */   \"createPath\": and go on...
```

How should I adjust config?

Comment: Shouldn't a react app include an index.html file?